# iOS - Multiple events on one button

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

Quite a newbie here.
I have 36 buttons connected to one action for the event Touch Up Inside. The action differentiates them by their tag. Now, when the same button is interacted with in a different way, either a double tap or a long press, I need a different set of instructions to be called, but I still need it to know which button was pressed. I've tried using gesture recognizers on the buttons, in addition to the button action, but they don't support tags. Any solutions?

Comment: if thy dont support tag, check by button title. if you can create an array of outlets/collection also

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Never use titles for that.

Comment: @user2342394 Note that the question is not about Xcode but about your iOS app, please refrain from misusing tags.

Comment: @H2CO3:  tag, title, 36outlets. What else?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya 1. **tag** (you can use `gestureRec.view.tag`), 2. associated objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still used tags with the gesture recognizers. Your recognizer handler has the gesture recognizer as the parameter to the method. From the gesture recognizer you have access to the associated view. And of course the view has the `tag` property.

```
- (void)myDoubleTapHandler:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    UIView *view = recognizer.view;
    int tag = view.tag;
}
```

Comment: Okay, how would I go about implementing this?

Comment: I just showed you. You create a gesture recognizer for each button. Use the same handler for every button just like you do for the touch event.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
int tag = gestureRec.view.tag;
```

?